# is it possible to pass a " Java 8 Method Reference" object to a stream?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, method-reference

I am looking to take a Method Reference i.e., `Person::getAge` and pass it as a parameter to use in a stream.

So instead of doing something along the lines of

```
personList.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(Person::getAge)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I am looking to do

```
 sortStream(personList, Person::gerAge)
```

and the sort Stream Method

```
public static void sortStream(List<Object> list, ???)
{

        list.stream()
            .sorted(Comparator.comparing(???))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

I have been looking around and found 2 types, one is `Function<Object,Object>` and the other is `Supplier<Object>` but none of them seemed to work.

The method itself seemed to be fine when using either a supplier or Function

```
 sortStream(List<Object>, Supplier<Object> supplier)
    {
     list.stream()
         .sorted((Comparator<? super Object>) supplier)
         .collect(Collectors.toList());
    
    }
```

but when calling      `sortStream(personList, Person::gerAge)`

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type:
```

There is no real error being shown so I'm not sure if there's an issue with Netbeans not detecting the error, or what (as this sometimes happens).

Does anyone have any advice on how I can solve this issue?  Thank you very much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> one is `Function<Object,Object>`

Use `Function<Person, Integer>`, and pass in a `List<Person>` too:

```
public static void sortStream(List<Person> list, Function<Person, Integer> fn) { ... }
```

If you want to make it generic, you could do:

```
public static <P, C extends Comparable<? super C>> void sortStream(
    List<P> list, Function<? super P, ? extends C> fn) { ... }
```

Or, of course, you could pass in a `Comparator<P>` (or `Comparator<? super P>`) directly, to make it clear what that parameter is for.

Comment: Thank you for the information.  It seems that by adding the generics code it gets rid of the error in the file, but I'm still presented with the `Erroneous sym type` error during runtime... However, your idea about passing a Comparator Object itself is exactly what I needed and works perfectly from what I see.. Thank you!  I'm not sure if the original way I wanted to do this will work (for curiosity sake), but the comparator answer works and doesn't change what I want to do.

Comment: “but I'm still presented with the Erroneous sym type error during runtime.” That’s a specialty of Netbeans. Try compiling the code with javac on the command line. It will give you either, specific errors or working code. By the way, your stream operation is pointless if you don’t use the result. If you want to sort the existing list, just call `sort` on the list.